# Fetching double value from Database and calculate with them

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I got another weird problem which i just don't understand.

I am saving doubles into my database with max. 3 digits after the decimal point.
The doubles are stored in the database correctly but when i am trying to fetch the data and add/multiply the stored doubles i get a weird problem

If i am storing data with only one digit after the decimal point, everything works fine and i get the right results. 
But if i am adding 2 or more digits after the decimal point my whole calculations won't work. I get no results into my TextViews.

I'm trying to understand whats happening for hours now but i just don't see why this happens.

Here is the code:

My MainActivity, where the TextViews get the Text:

```
public void calc() {
        // Get text for the statistics
        amount_widget.setText(db.getSearchResult("amount", 0));     
        lpayment_widget.setText(db.getSearchResult("price", 0));
        tpayment_widget.setText(db.getSearchResult("total_price", 1));
        mileage_widget.setText(db.getSearchResult("mileage", 2));
        trefueled_widget.setText(db.getSearchResult("amount", 1));

        // Calculate text for the consumption
        double consumption = (Double.parseDouble(db
                .getSearchResult("amount", 1)) / Double.parseDouble(db
                .getSearchResult("mileage", 2))) * 100;
        consumption = Math.round(consumption * 100) / 100.0;
        consumption_widget.setText(consumption + "L /100km");
    }
```

My Database Activity where the code is being fetched and calculated:

```
public String getSearchResult(String sql, int cmd) {

if (cmd == 0) {
    String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    String tmp = cursor.moveToFirst() ? cursor.getString(0) : "0";

    cursor.close();

    return tmp;
} else if (cmd == 1) {
    double sum = 0;
    String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    String idQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    Cursor id = db.rawQuery(idQuery, null);
    // berechnung
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    id.moveToFirst();

    int maxId = Integer.parseInt(id.getString(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

        double tmp = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        sum = sum + tmp;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    id.close();
    return String.valueOf(sum);
} else if (cmd == 2 && sql == "mileage") {
    double sum = 0;
    String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    String idQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    Cursor id = db.rawQuery(idQuery, null);
    // berechnung
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    id.moveToFirst();

    int maxId = Integer.parseInt(id.getString(0));
    if (maxId > 1) {
        int array[] = new int[maxId];

        // Array füllen
        for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            // sum = sum + tmp;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        for (int k = 1; k < maxId; k++) {
            double tmp;
            tmp = array[k] - array[k - 1];
            sum = sum + tmp;
        }

        cursor.close();
        id.close();
        return String.valueOf(sum);
    } else {
        return "--";
    }

}
return "Wrong CMD";
}
```

Comment: You should certainly be using DECIMAL, not DOUBLE, for money values.

Comment: @EJP I solved my issue and also replaced the double with BigDecimal.

Comment: And also replaced DOUBLE with DECIMAl in the database I hope?

Comment: I never had double in my Database. It was always Decimal. i think i just was not clear enough in my first post since i said i saved doubles in my database. By that I meant the variables are double which are saved declared as decimal in my database :D But good point! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

In my DbAdapter class within the `getSearchResult()` method i have the following statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

        double tmp = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        sum = sum + tmp;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

Here I am trying to parse an Integer but write it into a double. This is why the calculations couldn't be executed. I need to parse a double like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

        double tmp = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(0));
        sum = sum + tmp;
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

this is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're making a simple mistake. Instead of:
`consumption_widget.setText(consumption + "L /100km");`
try this:

```
consumption_widget.setText(String.valueOf(consumption) + "L /100km");
```

Comment: that does not solve the problem, i updated the textviews like that but i still don't get the proper results. Strange thing: after saving the first dacimal number with 2 digits after the point i do get a correct calculation, after restarting the app or after saving another value the problem occurs again.

Comment: And by the way, this shouldn't be a problem because the method in the DbAdapter class already returns strings...